# Start of an interview

Tags: passive-voice, politeness

Is it grammatically correct and should I start an interview saying this:

> “Thank you for the precious time that I have been granted.”

Comment: It is grammatically correct, but it sounds extremely flowery and overwrought to this US English speaker.  "Thank you for meeting with me" is fine.

Comment: I agree with @stangdon - leave out the word "precious." It's not always about being "grammatically correct"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical phrases to thank an interviewer for making time to meet with you are "Thank you for your time." or "I appreciate your taking the time to meet with me."